# pythonのreモジュールを用いた繰り返し表現の取得について

Tags: python, 正規表現

「どんどん」，「もぐもぐ」のように２文字の文字列を２回繰り返したものが入力された文字列に存在するかどうか確かめるプログラムを書きたいのですが，re.compileの引数をどのように書けば目的の文字列を表現するオブジェクトを生成できるでしょうか．
よろしくお願いいたします．

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2文字限定ならば以下でしょうか

```
(\S\S)\1
```

2文字に限らず繰り返しならば

```
(\S+)\1
```

\S =空白以外の文字
\1 =後方参照。()の文字を参照している。